# How to get a random float value between two floats?

Tags: java, random

The desired output is a random float between two floats. This is the way I did it but this method doesn't work for negative floats like: random float between -1f and -30f since the bound has to be positive and I get IllegalArgumentException. It also looks pretty complicated...if you have an easier approach that would be lovely. Cheers!

```
unitsConsumed = rnd.nextInt(Math.round(maxUnitsConsumed-minUnitsConsumed))+minUnitsConsumed;
```

Where rnd is an instance of Random.

Comment: generate random float and multiply it by -30

Comment: I trust that your min is -30 and your max is -1?

Comment: @JoeC it doesn't matter I only gave you an example.

Comment: @kret Could you tell me how :?

Comment: Actually, it does matter.  If your numbers are in the wrong places (i.e. max -30 and min -1), the error is expected.

Comment: Ohooaaa...lel. That's my baaad..Sorry you're so right! @joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    float result = rand.nextFloat() * (-1f - (-30f)) + (-30f);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: What data type is the last -30?

Comment: my mistake, fixed

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using the code below where min is your minimum value and max is your maximum value:

```
float random= rnd.nextFloat() * (max - min) + min;
```

Comment: btw the choice of `max` and `min` is arbitrary, the only difference is that `max -  min` is positive and `min - max` is negative.